# how to insert data into sqlite databse using Mono android with c#?

Tags: android, sqlite, c#-4.0, mono

I am trying to make my first application using Mono android with c# , table created without any error  but insert command is not working. Here is my code which is under Buttonevent  I have unknown error but don't know how to catch Exception please help.

```
 using Mono.Data.Sqlite;

     var documents = System.Environment.GetFolderPath( System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
     string db = Path.Combine(documents, "est.db3");

     SqliteConnection.CreateFile(db);

     if (File.Exists(db))
     {
        try
           {
             var conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + db);
             //string query = "CREATE TABLE ESTOQUE (ID INTEGER NOT NULL)";
             string query = "INSERT INTO  ESTOQUE (ID) VALUES (10)";
             conn.Open();
             SqliteCommand cm = new SqliteCommand(query, conn);
             cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
             conn.Close();
           }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
      }
```